# e.dataTransfer.setDragImage at full opacity

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am using the HTML5 Drag and Drop API. I have set a drag image using a visible node, but it is ghosted/partially transparent.

Setting the the drag image:

```
evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage(someVisibleElement, -12, -8);
```

Every example I see is translucent:

http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html

It looks like you cannot set opacity on this element, is this true?
No option is in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#setDragImage.28.29), but I was hoping someone could confirm. Seems strange to lock us in to 50% opacity if we can set an image.

Comment: Just an update after 20 days. I've accepted that it's impossible to change the opacity. Still surprised at the constraint though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set opacity on this element. Would love to be able to point to the part of the spec or bug report that notes this is the case.

Answer (score 5):

I didnt found easy way

but you can do it hard :-D.
create/clone element you want to see dragging, append to dom, set position fixed and between dragstart and dragend update his position according your mouse position.

Comment: True, you can definitely do this. The question was about the browser locking down the opacity of the dom element they provide though.

Comment: oh man why don't they have proper integration of this ): wouldn't that be super intensive?

Answer (score 1):

hide original image using event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0);
on dragstart. onDrag get the ghost image, update position using event.pageX, evenet.pageY

```js
onDrag(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const parentElement = <HTMLDivElement>(document.querySelector('.darggable-ghost-wrapper'));
    parentElement.style.position = "fixed";
    parentElement.style.left = event.pageX  + "px";
    parentElement.style.top = event.pageY + 5 +  "px";
    parentElement.style.opacity = ArhitectUtlityConstants.GHOSTPREVIEW.ghostOpacity;
    parentElement.style.border = "1px solid green !important";
}
```